# Вход без пароля в GDM

Tags: linux, password, login

Как сделать чтоб GDM не требовал пароля если ввести правильный TOTP?

Сейчас требует сначала токен потом пароль.

```
/etc/pam.d/system-auth                                                                       
#%PAM-1.0

auth      required  pam_google_authenticator.so
auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
....
```

Ставил optional - все равно просит.

А как сделать запрос пароля только при пустом otp?

Comment: `s/required/sufficient` у `pam_google_authenticator.so`?

Comment: кстати, по идее, при замене на `optional` у `pam_unix` должен пускать даже с неправильным паролем...

Comment: при sufficient не пускает вообще

Comment: проверил ([`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7CVn2Y89yM/)) на бубунте — УМВР и в `su`/`sudo`, и в `gdm`...

Comment: suceess=2 default=ignore наверное то что я искал

Comment: да, судя по всему это даже лучше... только `sucсess=1 …` в данном случае...